# ERROR Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, warnings

Yes I know questions like this have been asked but I have gone through all the ones I could find and still was not able to fix this issue. Maby this problem I am having will help others as well.

I am trying to make a camera app, but when i run the app it instantly fails. I have marked the spot where it fails and gives me the following warning...

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is the code, I have marked the part of it which gets the warning:

```
    import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var cameraPreviewlayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }

    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)

        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }

        currentCamera = backCamera
    }

    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!) //Here is the error-------
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer(){
        cameraPreviewlayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewlayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewlayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewlayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewlayer!, at: 0)
    }

    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    @IBAction func CameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_Segue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `setupDevice()` anywhere in the code and even if it was, you are setting `currentCamera` always to `backCamera` which might be `nil` if the device does not have back camera.

Just add the `setupDevice()` call to your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setupDevice()`in `override func viewDidLoad()`, before you call `setupInputOutput()`, to assign a value to `currentCamera` just like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCaptureSession()
    setupDevice()
    setupInputOutput()
    setupPreviewLayer()
    startRunningCaptureSession()

}
```